# Framework not found pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, linker-errors, xcode9.2

I know this is an old issue. But i produced this issue in a very strange way. Actually I had developed an app installed pods and everything in Deployment Target as 11.2. I took a an .ipa for it and sent it to the client for testing. But the Client is unable to install because the iPad Mini 1 is not having an iOS 10 or above update.
So I reduced the deployment target to 9.3 current iOS version of iPad Mini1 that the client is having. On taking an archive Xcode produces the error like this:
[image]

what is the issue?? Do we need to Unintall pods and install again or just modify the existing pod file? Please Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure your Podfile also specifies iOS 9.3 as the deployment target:

```
platform :ios, '9.3'
```

Comment: My Deployment target is the same, but still getting same error.

Answer (score 5):

I tried fixing my Podfile, but this didn't work for me.

I did the below to fix this issue :

Go to Project Navigator -> Targets -> OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension Target

under Frameworks and Libraries I found this :

[image]

I removed Pods_OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.framework

and build my project and it worked perfect.

Thank you

Comment: I really don't know if removing this item can cause any kind of unwanted effect but it solved the problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the POD dependency from Build Phases and then rebuilt the project, and it worked!

TARGETS -> Your app -> Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries -> remove POD from there by clicking the '-' button:
[image]

Then build the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Intel mac), setting the deployment target is the same (11.0) works for me:

1. pod file

[image: pod file]

2. Runner

[image: CleanShot 2022-12-20 at 22 40 23@2x]

3. One signal extension

[image: CleanShot 2022-12-20 at 22 41 40@2x]